# vuejs template conditional root element

Tags: vue-router, vuejs2

I'm making a generic vue button component.

In some cases it would be a router-link while in other cases it would be a normal anchor tag.

So basically looking for something like this.

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="useRouter" :to="link"></router-link>
  <a v-else :href="link"></a>
</template
```

But a vuejs component template must have exactly one root element.
Besides making two seperate vue components or wrapping my button in an element. I can't think of any other solution.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: whats wrong with wrapping it in an element such as a `<div>`?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing actually. But it just seems less clean.